# Does Cassandra considers millisecond while expring a column?

Tags: cassandra

I know for C* minimum TTL time is 1 second. But does it consider the millisecond part of of insertion time while expiring the column ?
For e.g. I inserted a record at 11:05:06:320 am with 1 second ttl.
I am expecting it to expire at 11:05:07:320 am
or it will expire at 11:05:07am ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A record inserted at 11:05:06:320 with 1 second TTL will expire at 11:05:07:000.

Cassandra calculates `localExpirationTime` for each expiring cell, which is local time in seconds plus TTL [1]. In your example, it will be 11:05:07. When Cassandra decides if a cell is alive, it checks that the current time is strictly less than expiration time [2]. As a result, starting at 11:05:07, our cell will be considered expired.

1. https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/ExpirationDateOverflowHandling.java#L118
2. https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/LivenessInfo.java#L330